# how to create a dll to reference and use in a separate project?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I want to create a dll from a class library in one solution, then add & reference that dll in a completely separate solution, so i can simply use those functions without having the whole class library in the project. Can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile the project in the solution and copy the `dll` for the specific project in question from the `bin` folder and place it in a solution items folder located in the other project. Then just add a reference to this `dll`, pointing to location of the `dll` in that solution item folder.

Comment: thanks! does the dll have to be in the 'References' folder of the new project, or can it exist anywhere?

Comment: No, it can be in a location the makes the most sense to your project/solution. In my case, I create a solutions folder and put all my external dlls there. That way everything is organized together.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a few of the classes from that project in the second solution one option would be to create a second project file and include only the classes you want.  You can either include them as linked files or put the project file in the same location as the original project file.

You can then just use the normal project reference technique.

The other option would be to reference the compiled dll as [Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8566674/89586) pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stand-alone .dll file with the following command line:

```
csc /target:library /out:<name of dll> <list of .cs files>
```

See more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).